# Looping through rows until criteria is met in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to loop over each row in my dataframe and if that row contains a 1, I'm looking "bf" to change to True so that the loop cancels and then prints out the index of row. Here's the code ive tried below.

```
bf <- FALSE
for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
   while(bf == FALSE){
      if(df[row, ] == 1){
         bf==TRUE
         print(row)
        
     }
   }
}
```

However what happens with this code is that it never seems to get if statement and execute it properly to my knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `apply`, `any`, `which` functions to id rows with a 1.  Then select the first row:

```
bdrows <- apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x == 1))
bd <- which(bdrows == TRUE)
firstbdrow <- bd[1]
```

Comment: I changed the bd to df and it works, thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked.  I fixed the error - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`bf==TRUE` is used for comparison, you might be looking for `bf = TRUE`. Also this doesn't operation doesn't require `for` or `while` loop. Let's say you have a column called `column_name` in your data you can do :

```
which.max(df$column_name == 1)
```

Or

```
which(df$column_name == 1)[1]
```

Comment: With the dataset I have I had to remove column names and row names

Comment: You can use `which.max(df[[1]] == 1)` for the 1st column.